# How do I take the advantage of OpenCL in an Emgu CV project

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, opencl, emgucv

I'm newbie in using Emgu CV and started to create small sample projects, for example face detection, eye detection,..etc. It would be good if I could take the advantage of OpenCL to accelerate the process using gpu. Otherwise, it causes massive cpu utilization when I decrease the scaleFactor. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know (from the official page of [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial) look at the bootom of the page) the `UMat` image format uses automatically the OpenCL Engine.
First you have to set the OpenCL to true by `CvInvoke.UseOpenCL = true`, then you need to create a `UMat` image format and then try to process that image.

At least that's what the official page of [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial) telling.

I tried this and work, it increased the perfomance quite a lot.