# Detection from video capture with EmguCV 3.1.0.1

Tags: c#, winforms, computer-vision, emgucv, face-detection

I'm trying to implement face detection with video capture using **EmguCV 3.1.0.1** library, installed by NuGet packages of VS15 on PC Windows 10 64-bit OS in WinForms desktop application.

My goal is to get detection and tracking of human face from videocamera and detect smile, but for examples below I will use only face `HaarCascade` .xml with `CascadeClassifier`.

So, my using with `DirectShowLib` library for `videoDevice` from `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` `SelectedItem`:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using DirectShowLib;
```

Path to HaarCascade xml-s:

```
    string facePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "dir\\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
```

Timer:

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        detectFace();
    }
```

Attempt 1:

```
    private void detectFace()
    {
        CascadeClassifier face = new CascadeClassifier(facePath);
        Image<Bgr, Byte> currentframe = null;
        Image<Gray, byte> grayFrame = null;
        Capture grabber;
        grabber = new Capture(videoDevice);
        currentframe = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(500, 320, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
        if (currentframe != null)
        {
            grayFrame = currentframe.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
            Rectangle[] faceDetected = face.DetectMultiScale(grayFrame, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);
            foreach (Rectangle faceFound in faceDetected)
            {
                currentframe.Draw(faceFound, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = currentframe.ToBitmap();
        }
    }
```

line  `currentframe = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(500, 320, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);` says:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'INTER' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Emgu.CV.CvEnum' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Instead I've tried to use `currentframe = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(500, 320, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed);`, with `grabber.QueryFrame().MatchTemplate` or `grabber.QueryFrame().Retrieve`, but another error still keeps in same line as:

> Error    CS1061  'Mat' does not contain a definition for
>   'Resize' and no extension method 'Resize' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'Mat' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

I'm not sure where I have to download required dll-s (if it is a reason of missing?) and which dll-s exactly I should add to references additionally.

Attempt 2:

```
    private Capture _capture;
    private CascadeClassifier _cascadeClassifier;
    private void detectFace()
    {
        _capture = new Capture(videoDevice); 
        _cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(facePath);
        using (var imageFrame = _capture.QueryFrame().ToImage())
        {
            if (imageFrame != null)
            {
                var grayframe = imageFrame.Convert();
                var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty);
                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    imageFrame.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Red), 3);
                }
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = imageFrame.ToBitmap();
        }
    }
```

line `using (var imageFrame = _capture.QueryFrame().ToImage())`:

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Mat.ToImage(bool)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the
>   type arguments explicitly.

line  `var grayframe = imageFrame.Convert();`:

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Image.Convert()' cannot be inferred from
>   the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

line  `imageFrame.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Red), 3);`:

> Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr'
>   to 'TColor'

Any guide, advice or example would be helpful

**Edit by *Michal Nawrocik* answer below:**

Method 1:

```
private void detectFace()
        {
            CascadeClassifier face = new CascadeClassifier(facePath);
            Image<Bgr, Byte> currentframe = null;
            Image<Gray, byte> grayFrame = null;
            Capture grabber;
            grabber = new Capture(videoDevice);  
            var dstMat = new Mat();
            var frame = grabber.QueryFrame();
            CvInvoke.Resize(frame, dstMat, new Size(500, 320), interpolation: Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Cubic);
            currentframe = dstMat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
            if (currentframe != null)
            {
                grayFrame = currentframe.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
                Rectangle[] faceDetected = face.DetectMultiScale(grayFrame, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);
                foreach (Rectangle faceFound in faceDetected)
                {
                    currentframe.Draw(faceFound, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
                }
                pictureBox1.Image = currentframe.ToBitmap();
            }
        }
```

Unhandled exception:

> System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.World.dll
>   Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Method 2:

```
 private Capture _capture;
    private CascadeClassifier _cascadeClassifier;
    private void detectFace()
    {
            _capture = new Capture(videoDevice);   
            _cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier(facePath);
            using (var imageFrame = _capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>())
            {
                if (imageFrame != null)
                {
                    var grayframe = imageFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
                    var faces = _cascadeClassifier.DetectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty);  
                    foreach (var face in faces)
                    {
                        imageFrame.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Red), 3);
                    }
                }
                pictureBox1.Image = imageFrame.ToBitmap();
            }
        }           
    }
```

exception:

> Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in Emgu.CV.World.dll Additional
>   information: OpenCV: Unrecognized or unsupported array type

Answer (score 0):

As your error message says, `Mat` class does not have a `Resize()` instance method, some quick googling reveals that you need to call the static method of `CvInvoke` class. The enum value for cubic interpolation has also been changed by developers of EmguCV at some point in time.

Here is the working code corresponding to your attempt 1:

```
var dstMat = new Mat();
var frame = grabber.QueryFrame();
CvInvoke.Resize(frame, dstMat, new Size(500, 320), interpolation: Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Cubic);
currentframe = dstMat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
```

Notice that I save references to `Mat` objects in order to dispose them later. `using` statements can also be used instead.

Your other problems are similar. There are no parameterless non-generic methods like `Mat.ToImage()` or `Image.Convert()`. They would not even make much sense because you need to specify what format you want to convert to.
In your case you can use:

```
var imageFrame =_capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
var grayFrame = imageFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
```

The last error in `Image.Draw()` call will disappear then.

Your problems suggest that you might benefit from taking a closer look at classes metadata available e.g. via Object Browser built in Visual Studio.

**Edit:**

In the first method you forgot to call `Dispose()` for some objects and this caused the exception. Here is the corrected code, tested and working:

```
private void detectFace()
{
    CascadeClassifier face = new CascadeClassifier(facePath);
    Image<Bgr, Byte> currentframe = null;
    Image<Gray, byte> grayFrame = null;
    Capture grabber;
    grabber = new Capture(videoDevice);
    var dstMat = new Mat();
    var frame = grabber.QueryFrame();
    CvInvoke.Resize(frame, dstMat, new Size(500, 320), interpolation: Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Cubic);
    currentframe = dstMat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
    if (currentframe != null)
    {
        grayFrame = currentframe.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
        Rectangle[] faceDetected = face.DetectMultiScale(grayFrame, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty, Size.Empty);
        foreach (Rectangle faceFound in faceDetected)
        {
            currentframe.Draw(faceFound, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);
        }

        var oldImage = panAndZoomPictureBox1.Image;
        panAndZoomPictureBox1.Image = currentframe.ToBitmap();
        if (oldImage != null)
        {
            oldImage.Dispose();
        }

        currentframe.Dispose();
        grayFrame.Dispose();
    }

    face.Dispose();

    grabber.Dispose();

    dstMat.Dispose();
    frame.Dispose();
}
```

I made the least possible fixes to make it work. There is quite some room for improvement. You can create `Capture` and `CascadeClassifier` just once instead of each timer tick, this will improve performance considerably.

I also noticed that the version of Emgu package you are using is quite old even though NuGet does not show newer version for this very package. The reason is it's been renamed to EMGU.CV.

Comment: Hello, thank you for feedback. I've edited code by your answer above, but both methods throws an unhandled exceptions, first is: `System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Emgu.CV.World.dll Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt` and second method: `Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' occurred in Emgu.CV.World.dll Additional information: OpenCV: Unrecognized or unsupported array type`

Comment: @viktor80 I edited my answer and added the code that lacked in your first method.

Comment: I'm sure this solution should work, but seems like it is something wrong there, at least, on my side. Image not smoothly moving, but hangs,  and coordinate of tracking rectangle faceFound.X or Y takes value with huge gap of time between freezing and moviment. I've used EmguCV 2 which is much older, with equivalent code, and works fine, the lack of old library verson for me is that the new haarcascade xml-s is not suitable for it. Where I can download last version of EMGU.CV and find useful examples?

Comment: EMGU.CV is available on NuGet, it's just a different package. I'm pretty sure there are ways to make your code perform better with the new version than with 2.x. On my PC after the minor modification I mentioned in my edit (creating `Capture` and `CascadeClassifier` once) the program works at full camera fps consuming ~30% CPU. Do you have an OpenCL capable GPU in the machine you need to run this program on? If so, maybe you can benefit from OpenCL in Emgu.CV like in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32035912/6866539
You can also try reducing the captured frame size.

Comment: Some examples are available at https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/tree/master/Emgu.CV.Example